# Why is the UINavigationBar turning black?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

**Problem:**

I have a `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Pressing a cell in the table view switches to another table view controller. In said table view controller, I'd like for the navigation bar to be invisible while still keeping the tab bar items so I added the following to its `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
```

For the first UITableViewController, I'd like the navigation bar to be normal so in its `viewDidAppear()` I did the following:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Everything is working fine except during the transition (which I am doing via `performSegueWithIdentifier`) the navigation bar on the first view controller disappears into blackness which looks ugly to be honest. Is there any way to prevent/fix this?

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: The solutions produced causes many other problems because they solve the problem but that not what the edgesForExtendedLayout for. maybe changing the background color for the app window to a color that suits the app is better:
'''self.window?.backgroundColor = .white''' in app delegate.

Answer (score 19):

I ran into this again recently, and discovered a way to fix it in the storyboard. If you're using opaque navigation bars, ensure the "Extend Edges" setting for "Under Opaque Bars" is set. In fact, I just set all three of them as shown below:-

[image]

Comment: This solution worked for me for iOS 15 issue that just appeared. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Just change your navigationController view's backgroundColor

```
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = // whatever
```

Answer (score 13):

iOS 15 changed the way nav bars rendered. They are transparent by default. In most cases by default, no content is beneath the nav bars resulting in black color. The following code in AppDelegate(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) fixed that for me.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        //Configure additional customizations here
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I had a very similar problem recently. Try setting `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true` in both view controllers and `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone`. 
Storyboard version: [Extended Edges - Under Top Bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOR26.png)

Comment: Setting self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change the window background color for you application to a color that suits you:

```
self.window?.backgroundColor = .white
```

**Other solutions causes other problems in multiple inner screens.**

Comment: This unfortunately causes some visual issues with iOS 13's new modal presentation style. If you aren't using them, this works great

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the translucency of the navigation bar. So in the `viewDidLoad` for your second `UITableViewController`, you can write the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .blackColor()

    // Play around with the duration until you find
    // a time interval, you find suitable
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but there's no balance between the nav bar disappearing fast enough and the black part appearing. I'm trying to think of a workaround

Comment: What do you mean by balance? Because when I am running the code snippet above in the simulator, then it looks quite good. Could you make a small QuickTime recording of how it looks for you with the animation of the translucency?

Comment: What speed are you using? And unfortunately I can't because this project is for a client. Anyway what I'm trying to say is that too slow of a speed leads to the navigation bar still being visible temporarily in the second view controller and two fast leads to the black part appearing. If you want to know what I'm trying to achieve check out the music app in iOS 8.4 or iOS 9 when checking out an album with its songs.

Answer (score 1):

On viewDidLoad add:

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Answer (score 1):

for me otherwise helped (**Swift 5**):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green //change to needed color
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code helped me to get rid of **black navigationBar** in **iOS 15+**

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
            appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 125/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            appearance.shadowColor = .clear  //removing navigationbar 1 px bottom border.
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me,

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
     UINavigationBarAppearance *appearance = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
     [appearance configureWithOpaqueBackground];
     [appearance setBackgroundColor:UIColor.yellowColor];
     appearance.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor};
     controller.navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance;
     controller.navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
     controller.navigationItem.compactAppearance = appearance;
 }
```